# Grafana -- Zabbix Data Source cannot connect

Tags: grafana, zabbix

I've got my system all set up with Zabbix and love it for my detailed monitoring.
I need to put a pretty wrapper on it for displaying on our status screen and have been trying to use Grafana but cannot seem to get the Zabbix Data Source correctly connected.
I've hunted all around for more detailed documentation -- is there any?

OR Does anyone who has done this have some hints about what I can try?

Thanks in advance -- James

Comment: How did you configure it? Would make sense to add some details, right?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install "Zabbix plugin for Grafana"

https://grafana.com/plugins/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app

Use the grafana-cli tool to install Zabbix from the command line:

```
grafana-cli plugins install alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app
```

Comment: I've wrote a series on how to install and integrate zabbix & grafana. Hope this will help http://mjmohebbi.com/en/blog/How-to-Install-Zabbix-and-Grafana-to-monitor-things-PART-1

Answer (score 0):

If you have compatibility issues, check this solution

https://github.com/alexanderzobnin/grafana-zabbix/issues/1419

In my case I have grafana running on windows server working perfectly with the following steps:

1. -Install grafana 8.5 on Windows Server 2019
2. -Install Plugin 2.4.6 via CMD (C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\bin grafana-cli plugins install alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app)
3. -Go to C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\data\plugins\alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app\datasource-zabbix and create new folder with name , "datasource-zabbix"
4. -copy the "partials" folder and copy inside the created folder "datasource-zabbix"
5. -Delete MANIFEST file on C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\data\plugins\alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app
6. -add: allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app, alexanderzobnin-zabbix-datasource, alexanderzobnin-zabbix-triggers-panel in the configuration file (config.ini for Windows Version)
7. -Restart Grafana Service